# Textbox Autofill in php

Tags: php, mysql, autofill

I am having a hard time in making my homework. I am trying to make a sales invoice system that automatically fills the other fields when one field's value changes without reloading the page. I've tried using sessions but its not working well because I need to refresh the page.

I've successfully made the item description fetch data from my sql and it should provide the unit of the item I chose. can anybody help me?

here is my whole code:

```
function suggestValues() {
$("#field").autocomplete("suggestions.php", {
width: 256,
selectFirst: false
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
suggestValues();
});

<body>
<form name="search" method="post" action="enter_sales2.php">

<table>
<tr> 
<td> Receipt #: </td>
<td> <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" name="receiptNum"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Customer Name: </td>
<td> <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="50" name="customerName"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td>Qty</td>
<td> Item Description </td>
<td> Unit </td>
<td> Amount </td>
<td> Total </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" size="5" name="qty1"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" size="39" name="item1" id="field" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" size="5" name="unit1"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" size="5" name="amt1"> </td>
<td> <input type="type" size="8" name="total1"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is my php file for the search:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("consteel", $con);

function autosuggest() {
    $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM item WHERE item_name LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 10");
    while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
        $item_name = $result['item_name'];
        if (strpos(strtolower($item_name), $q) !== false) {
        echo "$item_name\n";
        }
    }
}
autosuggest();
?>
```

please help me in this..

Comment: You should remove all these spaces from the start of code here, it is hard to read when you'll have to scroll to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same way you have used for autocomplete. You have to use ajax. Once someone enter the order number you can make a ajax request to your php page and then populate form data using the response.

You may read following articles. I can't write all the code since it's bit lengthy.

http://www.crackajax.net/popform.php

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxxml9/

Seems you are using jquery. So your work will be more easy.

Comment: I'm not sure about it.. but can you give me a snippet of the code you're talking about???? as well as the php code. I'm really having a hard time right now..

Comment: @GeorgeNormanPatayon No. This is your homework. You must do the research and read the code yourself so you can implement it into your current code. People will not give you code answers for your homework. They will however point you in the right direction. Google for "jquery autocomplete" You are using jquery, so you are ALMOST there! =]